# Google Maps API v3 Loading Only After Page Refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm fiddling around with the Google Maps API for a webpage I'm working on. My issue right now is, the map loads exactly as I intend it to but only after refreshing the page. If I do not refresh the page, all I see is the canvas. The problem remains if I leave the page and return to it so it appears to be an issue with calling for the map to `initialize`.

The code:

```
<style>
    #map_canvas {
    width: 670px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #CCC;
    }
</style>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script>
    function initialize() {

        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(31.247681, 121.449504);

        var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');

        var map_options = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(31.248195, 121.447431),
        zoom: 16,
                mapTypeControl: false,
                panControl: false,
        zoomControlOptions: {
                    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER
        },
        streetViewControl: false,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options);

        var contentString =
            '<b>Leung Gallery</b>' +
            '<p>50 Moganshan Rd. Building 7, Unit 108, Shanghai</p>' +
            '<p>&#19978;&#28023;&#26222;&#38464;&#21306;&#33707;&#24178;&#23665;&#36335;50&#21495;7&#21495;&#27004;108&#23460;</p>';

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
        });

        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });

    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>​
```

Browsing through previous questions, I haven't found anything that matched my problem exactly but I've seen some similar situations that revolved around `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);` so I'm thinking that might be where the issue is. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: Got pointed in the right direction. Adding `$(document).bind("projectLoadComplete", initialize);` after `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);` fixes the issue. The issue was that the pages were not fully loading when using the navigation. This issue is probably exclusive to the Cargo Collective platform.

Comment: Its loading as expected check out this fiddle..http://jsbin.com/ofutUbA/1/edit

Comment: @codebreaker could it maybe be the environment I'm using this in? i'm building my webpage using cargo collective. not sure if maybe that has an influence on why the map only initializes AFTER refreshing the page.

Comment: k in ur code where is this script code in head section or after body as in my code fiddle..

Comment: If anyone would like to take a look at the issue at hand, it's on [this page](http://leunggallery.com/about)

Comment: @codebreaker the script is, i believe, in the head section. Cargo Collective is a pretty restrictive environment for placing code. I'll play around with this and see if I can place the script inside the body.

Comment: u should place the code after the body tag and then see the results..if not reply back..

Comment: @DarrylLeung the link u posted i opened in chrome loads the map without any refresh may ur environment might be a issue..elsewhere works fine..

Comment: @codebreaker your comment gave me an idea. I decided to input, into my browser, the direct page URL and it loaded up perfectly fine. The problem seems to be that when I jump from the homepage (or any other page) using the navigation, it doesn't load the map and only shows the canvas until I refresh the page. This might be beyond the scope of the question I originally posed. Probably something to do with the inner workings of Cargo Collective instead.

Comment: When I input the url directly in IE it does not work fine for me, fyi.

Comment: in fact, right now it's not even working anymore after refreshes! very strange...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got pointed in the right direction. Adding `$(document).bind("projectLoadComplete", initialize);` after `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);` fixes the issue. The issue was that the pages were not fully reloading when using the navigation. This issue is probably exclusive to the Cargo Collective platform. I am guessing it is a decision they made to make the page transitions faster.

Answer (score 5):

After several hours of unsuccessful search for a solution finally I found this:

Just replace:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  initialize();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems to work fine for me in Firefox, but not in Internet Exploder. In IE the first view of the page the map does not load. I am pretty certain that it has got to do with the way the page is being built. When I view source in IE and do a search for the text "map_canvas" (which is of course the id of your div for the map to display in) I am not able to find a div or any html element with that id within the raw page source for some reason, and I have not actually figured out how it's being added in to the page. But, the div does show up in Developer Tools as an empty xml element: <div id="map_canvas" /> which upon subsequent refresh of the page it gets filled in. This leads me to believe that whatever other code you have which must be adding that div to the page dynamically it is running after your map initialization script. So, if you have the ability to move your initialize map script the best place to put it would be immediately before the closing </body> tag. If it still does not work properly then, you may want to try and delay your initialize script from running even a bit more, try:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(
    window,
    'load',
    function () {
         //1000 milliseconds == 1 second,
         //play with this til find a happy minimum delay amount
        window.setTimeout(initialize, 1000);
    }
);
```

Comment: I just attempted to alter the that portion of the script and, for a moment, I thought it worked. I was able to use the navigation to get to the about page and it loaded correctly. However, I wasn't able to replicate results. I have also tried inserting the script into, what I'm assuming is, the body portion of the HTML. That didn't work. That section accepts some HTML (`div` for instance) I am using Cargo Collective as my platform so I'm quite limited as to how I can alter the HTML.

Comment: I'm came back here to give this answer an upvote. Then after reading the whole answer, I moved the bootstrap.js above the map initialize. Works like a charm without the need for the setTimeout. The setTimeout works as well. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In API version 3 call

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')
```

or for version 2

```
map.checkResize()
```

Make sure you call `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')` **BEFORE** calling `map.fitBounds()` or you will get unexpected results.

Answer (score 1):

I have checked this and its working fine for me. Please checkout the `fiddle` http://jsfiddle.net/aCx6L/

Answer (score 0):

After trying out various suggestions and failed, I found that the following works for me:

```
try {google;} catch (e){location.reload();}
```

You should add this just before the creating the map.

I know this may not be the best solution as it incurs extra load on the server.

I also found out that the map can load correctly the first time round in Internet Explorer The Edge but not in Google Chrome.